# Clicking on label not working in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a custom file selection button in HTML and CSS.
I've read on the internet that it can be done, hiding the original button and 'drawing' a new one over it, like so:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="upload">
        <input type="file" class="upload" name="upload"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.upload {
    width: 157px;
    height: 57px;
    background-color: silver;
}

div.upload input {
    display: block !important;
    width: 157px !important;
    height: 57px !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

And it's working, obviously... but I want only a text, not a image.
So I tried it like this way:

```
<div class="upload">
        Choose File
        <input type="file" class="upload" name="upload"/>
</div>
```

And it won't work when I click on the label. It only works when I click below it.

[image]

Why doesn't this work and how can I make this work? I also tried with `pointer-events` and nothing...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to assign your text to your `<button>`, using a `<label>` with a `for` attribute equal to the `id` of the `<input>`.

```
<div class="upload">
  <label class="uploadLabel" for="uploadBtn">  Choose File</label>
  <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" name="upload" />
</div>
```

In order to completely cover the button with your label, you'll also have to add absolute positioning.

```
.uploadLabel {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/xEomPp)

**Why is this necessary?**

The event is triggered on your button. This basically means, clicking on a plain text element won't do anything. To trigger a click event on your button, you simply delegate the click on your label to your button.

Comment: Wow, that was unexpectedly easy... Thanks!

Comment: this does not work if you click the label to the right of the text. i wouldn't accept this. also, this perpetuates the flawed approach of granting the wrapper and the input the same dimensions - this is not very flexible; you'd have to change both to alter the box dimensions.

Comment: @EliranMalka Oh, now I saw it... The right side doesn't work... That's somewhat sad. I think your approach may be a bit longer, but works better... I'll rethink the accepted answer again.

Comment: I didn't think this was about a competition right now. Edited my answer.

Comment: @Fusseldieb - i updated my demo to be significantly shorter.

Comment: @Aer0 - it's always about a competition :)

Comment: Oh...I think I'm in trouble now. Both work and both are short... I don't know which one I should accept.

Comment: @Fusseldieb To be honest, my approach is way easier to implement and also has a much larger application range. You could even set your label next to a button and it would stil delegate and trigger your event. Anyways, it's up to you to select the answer which fits your desires. I'm just glad I could help. I don't need those 25 points that much.

Comment: @Fusseldieb - it's really up to you to decide what works best. both approaches work fine (this one may have to be slightly tweaked to get the full clickable area). also, don't take it too seriously, it's all just virtual points anyways :)

Comment: @EliranMalka Thanks for taking it easy, but I really wanted to give points to both of you, because it's not that easy to write a such complete answer, it takes time and effort. So, as of now,I don't know which one to accept, because both are working completely fine. If we don't come to a 'winner', I'll randomly choose one on http://random.org :)

Answer (score 3):

1. use an actual `label` element. that will take care of delegating the click from the container to the input.
2. set `opacity` to `0`, as you did in your original post (another, more verbose, and arguably more semantic approach will be to position the input absolutely and the label relatively, and set a lower `z-index` to the input. that will cover the input completely, effectively hiding it — see the second example).

the benefit here is you get clickable area that matches the label surface only, so you can style and set the dimensions to the label alone.

```css
.upload {
  display: block;
  width: 157px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.upload input {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="upload">
  Choose File
  <input type="file" class="upload" name="upload" />
</label>
```

… and the more verbose approach:

```css
.upload {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 157px;
  height: 57px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.upload input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="upload">
  Choose File
  <input type="file" class="upload" name="upload" />
</label>
```

Comment: you could make it a lot shorter, just by setting the input to opacity 0. updating the answer accordingly